# Excel-VBA run-time error thrown if .Activate is not called before use of .AxisGroup on NewSeries series

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a Macro for an Excel spreadsheet to update a chart and add a vertical "Now Line" to easily locate the date.

I have searched but the error seems to be behaving unlike any other. When excel first starts, the first run of the Macro will always fail UNLESS I look at the sheet with the chart-to-be-updated at least once before running the macro.

Any run after the first will always succeed, even if the first run failed. This seems pretty unique to me, and my guess is that the some chart properties are not being loaded into memory when excel starts.

This led me to my workaround, which was to include an .Activate statement for the chart containing the series prior to setting the series' properties.

```
Set Primary_Chart = Charts("Chart")

'Create the new series
Set NowLine_Series = Primary_Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

'Fails without this
Primary_Chart.Activate 

'Set the series' properties
With NowLine_Series
    .Name = "=""Now"""
    .Values = "='Pulldown Options'!$q$2:$q$3"
    .XValues = "='Pulldown Options'!$p$2:$p$3"
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

    'This is the trouble line. Hangs here
    .AxisGroup = 1 'Share axis with other series

    .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse 
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Line.Weight = 3.5
    .Format.Line.Style = msoLineThickBetweenThin
    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(36, 255, 5)
End With
```

I know it is bad practice to use .Activate so I am trying to figure out a way around this. I've had no luck after a few hours.

Here are the details of the error when the Primary_Chart.Activate line in not present.

```
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)'

Method 'AxisGroup' of object 'Series' failed
```

Comment: Is this code in `Workbook_Open`?

Comment: This is code from my own ChartUpdate() procedure.

Comment: I believe the error you're getting is "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" if that helps.  I'd also take a look at the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140463/excel-vba-chart-axis-error-method-scaletype-of-object-axis-failed-when-re).

Comment: I had seen that question but it didn't seem to suggest a solution. I looked into the "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" error but that looks like it stems from many different issues. The error itself is rather generic. It does look like the error I'm getting, however, I don't think it will help much. I will continue to look at it.

Comment: I was able to run your code without error on a simple example chart. Could you give more details to help replicate the error? Is your chart a combination chart? Do you have primary/secondary axes? Is the code you're running in the same workbook as the chart?

Comment: That's strange. The chart is a combination chart with both a primary and secondary axis, but the secondary axis is hidden. The macro is running on the same workbook (not the same worksheet, however). It is a fairly detailed excel document, I think the key clue is that the Macro runs fine so long as I look at the chart at least once before running the macro. I don't know excel well enough to know what is running when I switch to view a different sheet. I'm pretty sure it calls something to Activate the worksheet, but I don't know the details.